# customerror remoteonly not showing details on server ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, custom-errors

I am trying to view the detailed stack trace on the server but it displays the friendly page.

Here is the configuration of my webConfig

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="/www/pageerror.aspx">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/www/PageNotFound.aspx" />
</customErrors>
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" />
    ...
<...system.webServer>
```

I access the website from the local server with the regular https:/www... URL.

How do I view the detailed stack trace when set with RemoteOnly?

As a side note, on the pageError.aspx I have a code supposed to show the last Server Error but it always return null like there was no error. Not sure if it is linked:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (User.IsEmployee())
        {
            System.Exception error = Server.GetLastError();
            if (error != null)
                literalError.Text = error.Message.Trim();
            else
                literalError.Text = "no error found";
            placeHolderError.Visible = true;
        }

    }
```